# Git status shows a weird string as an untracked file

Tags: git

Git status gives me this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        "\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

There is no such file or directory:

```
$ cat $"\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q"
cat: '\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q': No such file or directory
```

Another weird thing is that the status command before the last commit did not show this weird path string.

Any idea what is going on? should I *"git clean -f"*? is it safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For Ubuntu/Linux :**

Simply remove it command using :

```
sudo rm -rf "\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q"
```

This Happens when a script/command outputs as a newfile with such characters.

**For Windows :**

1) Go to `Folder Options` => Select `Show Hidden & System Files`

2) Browse to your Repository folder.

3) Remove the file named with `"\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q"`

Comment: I'm on windows and don't have sudo. rm -rf "\357\200\233\357\200\233OB\357\200\233q" didn't do the job. What I did is git clean -f and it worked. I wonder what happened there. what script/command did this and why it was not detectable as a folder/file.

Comment: Answer updated, & yes its Cool, because the file must be created using system & must be hidden, using `git clean -f` the file is cleared & your internally called `git checkout branchname -f`

Comment: Thanks for the info LuFFy.

Comment: I have the same issue, but with another string `"\342\200\234/"`. I have tried to use `sudo rm -rf "\342\200\234/"`, and `git clean -f`, but sadly none of them work. (I am on macOS Mojave)

Comment: Just a note that the filename can look differently in explorer: mine was ` \357\200\233q\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233q` in git status (=raw byte string), but `qq` in explorer. Bottom line: Just find a weird fresh file in a repo root with half-git half-gibberish contents and delete it.